# wp_mail Allow Remote Attachments from CDN

Tags: attachments, wp-mail, cdn

I came across a problem with WP_Mail for sending form submissions with file attachments. Our site uses a CDN, so everything uploaded to the site, whether images and media by site builders or documents by users gets put on an external server.

This poses a problem for WP_Mail because it uses the PHPMailer addAttachment method to attach files, which expects local files. I was able to fix this by changing the line in wp_mail to use addStringAttachment, but of course modifying core files isn't really a fix. What is the right way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: you can always write the file to a temporary folder, attach it, send, then delete it

Answer (score 0):

Solved by Tom J Nowell's suggestion. Our form plugin fortunately has a filter before the data is passed to wp mail, so there I was able to swap the attachment url for one pointing to the temporary folder.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).